# How to read values from class name

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, dom-traversal

I have the following table:

```
<table>
    <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th class="tTle">Mon</td>
            <th class="tTle">Tues</td>
            <th class="tTle">Wed</td>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class = "Val1"/>
                <input type="text" class = "Val2"/>
                <input type="button" class = "but" val="monday"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class = "Val1"/>
                <input type="text" class = "Val2"/>
                <input type="button" class = "but" val="tuesday"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class = "Val1"/>
                <input type="text" class = "Val2"/>
                <input type="button" class = "but" val="wednesday"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class = "Val1"/>
                <input type="text" class = "Val2"/>
                <input type="button" class = "but" val="monday"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class = "Val1"/>
                <input type="text" class = "Val2"/>
                <input type="button" class = "but" val="tuesday"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class = "Val1"/>
                <input type="text" class = "Val2"/>
                <input type="button" class = "but" val="wednesday"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class = "Val1"/>
                <input type="text" class = "Val2"/>
                <input type="button" class = "but" val="monday"/>
            </td>>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class = "Val1"/>
                <input type="text" class = "Val2"/>
                <input type="button" class = "but" val="tuesday"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class = "Val1"/>
                <input type="text" class = "Val2"/>
                <input type="button" class = "but" val="wednesday"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to read the respective `thead` value for `tTle` when I click on `but`? How can I do that?

```
$(function ()
    {
        
         $(".but").click(readTitle);      
            
  
        });
});
```

Comment: i think you got some html structure error `</td>><td` inside input

Comment: I reformatted your code and hopefully the structure error that experimentX mentions are more obvious

Comment: @DTing..each `tr` should have 3 `TD`, i again formatted... jopefully perfect :)

Comment: also added `value` attribute to `<input type=button`

Comment: @diEcho Usually it is a good idea to not change the original question posted by too much. Now the answer is somewhat trivial, and different than what is applicable to the original poster's question. You might want to revert that edit and post your suggestion as an answer or comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood well, if a button is clicked, you want to get which column is this button in, and the determine the `thead` title for that column. My little snippet does that:

```
$('.but').click(function () {
  var $me=$(this);
  var place=$('td', $me.closest('tr')).index($me.closest('td'));

  var text=$('thead .tTle').eq(place).text();
});
```

In `place`, the 0-based position of the button's parent `td` will be stored. This can be fetched using [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/), which is executed on the set of `td`'s in the corresponding `tr` and gets the position of our `td` inside that.

When we have the index, it is easy to find the `.tTle` we are looking for using [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

**Edit**: And the promised [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/SrB6p/). It seems to work fine, though OP indicated in the comments below this answer that it has to be changed. Might be some markup problems.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it seems to be readiung the title of the column next to the but clicked and not its corresponding title

Comment: The answer would be complete if we do it like this:  var text=$('thead .tTle').eq(place-1).text();

Comment: @user281180 I will post a jsFiddle soon, but I cannot access it right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `elem.className` or, if you prefer using a jQuery method, `$(elem).attr('className')`. In your event handler, `this` is the `elem`.

However, to store arbitrary data, the HTML5 data attributes (also work fine without actually setting a HTML5 doctype) are better:

`<sometag data-something="text-or-json">` and `$('...').data('something')`

Answer (score -1):

try the following `Javascript` code

```
$(function ()
                {

                    $(".but").click(function(){

                        alert("here");
                        var nTd = this.parentNode;
                        alert(nTd.getElementsByClassName("Val1")[0].value)
                        alert(nTd.getElementsByClassName("Val2")[0].value)
                    });


                });
```